# Convert string to array using regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have this string:

```
$string = ["coffee candy (123456789) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)",
           "fruity candy (987654332) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)"];
```

I want a result to be like this:

```
array(2) {
 [0] => array {
    ["name"] => string(12) coffee candy
    ["num"] => string(9) 123456789
    ["amount"] => string(15) Amount 0.00 EUR
 }
 [1] => array {
    ["name"] => string(12) fruity candy
    ["num"] => string(9) 987654332
    ["amount"] => string(15) Amount 0.00 EUR        
 }
}
```

Or something similar. Is it possible with a regular expression? If so, how?

Comment: Show us what regexes you have tried in order to solve this.

Comment: that string is an array already

Comment: it's a string.. pls believe me. It came in that format unfortunately

Comment: then it probably is `$string = '["coffee candy (123456789) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)","fruity candy (987654332) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)"]';` (note the single quotes), for [] is the shorthand of array()

Comment: when i print_r($string[0]) it outputs:
[

Comment: Please read some tutorials about PHP & regexes and show what you have tried or hire a programmer if you just want a solution.

Comment: A *"write the code for me"* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
<?php
$text = 'coffee candy (123456789) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)';

preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s+?\(([\d]+)\)\s+?\((.+)\)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string with char `(`, then trim `)`, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/807031)

```
<?php

$string = ["coffee candy (123456789) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)",
           "fruity candy (987654332) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)"];
$keys = ['name', 'num', 'amount'];          
$array = array_map(function($v) use($keys) {
  $arr = explode('(', $v);
  $arr = array_map(function($v){
    return trim($v, " \t\n\r\0\x0B)");
  }, $arr);
  return array_combine($keys, $arr);
}, $string);

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the input is consistent (machine generated) I'd drop regex and go for something like this

```
$array = explode(',',$string);
foreach($array as $data){
    $parts = explode('(',$data);
    $result[]['name'] = trim(substr($parts[0], 1));
    $result[]['num'] = trim(substr($parts[1], 0, -1));
    $result[]['amount'] = trim(substr($parts[2], 0, -2));
}
```

However this will only work with consistent strings.

Comment: note that if one of the parts contains a `,`, say `"coffee candy (123456789) (Amount: 0.00 EUR)"` this will give unexpected results

Comment: Yes it will be bad making it an inconsistent string since ',' was used as a markup.